# Работа с числами в winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        a *= 2;
        textBox4.Text = a.ToString();
    }
```

Почему то не выводит число в textBox4

Comment: У меня этот код работает. Не вижу проблем, при условии что в textBox2 введено число.

Comment: Всё должно работать, посмотри дебаг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался у меня почему то button1_Click как будто не существовало.
Пересоздал автоматически через 2е нажатие на элемент и все заработало.
Так и не понял почему когда написал в ручную не работало мб из за регистра???

Comment: Потому что просто иметь в форме метод `Button1_Click` - недостаточно. В другом куске `partial` класса формы есть строчка `Button1.Click += Button1_Click;`.